ScreenConnect Remote PC shut down
I'm working on a remote PC cloud machine (Via Hetzner). While working, I accidentally shut down the windows computer running on the remote PC. Now, when I try to reconnect, it says:
Waiting for your guest...
You have successfully connected to the session, but your guest has not yet connected. Your session will start when they connect.
I'm worried that I can't get back in again. I tried reboot and restart, and also waking it, but nothing works. Is there a way to fix this and reconnect? Thanks.

You might want to talk with Hetzner's Tech support. We aren't Hetzner, so there isn't much we can do to help unless someone had the same issue and has a solution.

This is a hardware issue, i.e., have someone at the physical site help.
